# Dart streaming performance

Tags: dart, dart-io

Apologies if this question is deemed inappropriate for SO, but I was wondering if any of you know if there's a significant performance difference between streaming futures via `asStream` and consuming futures normally via `then`. Would you expect a general performance difference between the following two operations?

#### Operation 1

```
expensiveOperation().asStream().listen((res) {
  doSomething(res);
});
```

#### Operation 2

```
expensiveOperation().then((res) {
  doSomething(res);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asStream` just allocates a wrapper object and forwards the future's outcome to the stream. All in all you probably won't notice the difference.

If you happen to have a case where you actually measure a slow-down, file a bug on http://dartbug.com. There are still ways to make the wrapper cheaper.